# Power bi : importing nest json query with

Tags: json, powerbi

I want to import the below json using power bi. I've imported flatter jsons before but not with so many nested records and lists.  For example, lets take the "answers" record, it has 5 more records and that are the same structure, lets then "initial_question" record has values list, a record inside that, then a field name record, then the value that i want. Any ideas how to do this in power bi ?

```
{"metadata":
    {"device_id":"Android_cfb576b2-XXXXXX","user_id":null,"username":"XXXXXXX","submitted_at":"2019-12-10 18:52:16 +00:00","received_at":"2019-12-10 18:52:14 +00:00","submission_id":"42776798","device_submission_identifier":"5e071197-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","submission_counter":"1","form_name":"2. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ","form_version":"1.02"},

"answers":
    {"initial_questions":{"values":[{"conducted_on":{"value":"2019-12-10"},"start_time":{"value":"2019-12-10 14:45:32"},"shift":{"value":"afters"},"operator_name_":{"value":"XXXXXXXXXXXX"},"Machine":{"value":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}}]},

    "Work_Information":{"values":[{"Part_number":{"value":"XXXXXXXXXX"},"_1st_or_2nd_end_Machining":{"value":"Both"},"Work_Area_Tidy_":{"value":"Yes"},"Yes_No_Question":{"value":true}}]},

    "Pre_machining_checks":{"values":[{"Head_Bearings_Greased_":{"value":"N/A"},"check_cuttings_tips":{"value":true},"Checked_Oil_level":{"value":true},"check_measuring_and_gauging_equipment__micrometer_ect_":{"value":true},"Check_coolant":{"value":true},"Check_process_sheets":{"value":true},"First_off_ok_":{"value":"01FWHSBGOOFJI6RXSARNBJE4YV2FHWIUJJ"}}]},

    "Lost_Time":{"values":[{"_1st_off_cut":{"value":10.0},"Setup_machine_centre":{"value":0},"Tool_change":{"value":0},"Wait_for_Fork_Lift_Truck_driver":{"value":0},"Wait_Fork_Lift_Truck":{"value":20},"meal_break___tea_Break___Wash_Off":{"value":20},"Clean_machine_centre_scrap_out":{"value":30},"Fill_Coolant":{"value":15},"Other_lost_time":{"value":0}}]},

    "Post_Machine_checks":{"values":[{"Last_off_cut_ok_":{"value":"01FWHSBGN45Z2E673KFRCZOGXSILA7T75A"},"Head_bearings_greased_":{"value":false},"Checked_cutting_Tips_":{"value":true},"Checked_measuring_equipment__micrometer_ect_":{"value":true},"Checked_Coolant_Levels":{"value":true},"Process_Sheets_Returned_":{"value":true}}]},

    "end_of_shift_report":{"values":[{"Number_of_good__compliment__parts_produced_":{"value":80},"Number_Of_parts_scrapped_":{"value":0},"Number_of_parts_reworked__":{"value":0},"Tooling_Last_off_ok_":{"value":"pass"},"End_Time_":{"value":"2019-12-10 21:15:07"},"Tooling_ok_after_last_off_":{"value":true},"Working_area_tidy_":{"value":true},"Any_comments_not_captured_above_":{"value":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"},"End_Time":{"value":"2019-12-10 21:15:37"}}]}
    }
}
```

Here's the screens shows of the process, thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the lists into tables and go on expanding the columns to new Values or Rows, and see if it shapes into what you want. Unpivot columns when needed.
If it doesn't help, you might have to separate some of that records into new queries, and build several tables.